# Convert to alphanumeric a sequential file generated by COBOL with compacted data

Tags: unicode, vbscript, cobol, sequential

I have a COBOL program which generates a sequential file with this structure:

```
FD ALUMNOS-FILE.
01 ALUMNOS-DATA.
    88 EOF                 VALUE HIGH-VALUES.
    05 STUDENTID           PIC 9(7).
    05 STUDENTNAME         PIC X(10).
    05 FILLER              PIC X(8).
    05 COURSECODE          PIC X(4).
    05 FOO                 PIC S9(7)V USAGE COMP-3.
```

If I open the file in Notepad++, I see strange unicode symbols which are difficult to read caused by the `COMP-3` variable. Something similar to the image below (the image is from another file):

[image]

Is there any way **without using COBOL** to rewrite this sequential file to be readable? Maybe using a script language like VBS? Any tip or advice will be appreciated, and if you need more info let me know and I'll edit the post.

Comment: BTW that's Notepad++, not Notepad.

Comment: @BillWoodger: Since Stack Overflow was created only in 2008 (not 1990), you may safely assume that my comment was a joke, yes.

Comment: The "COMP" bit means "COMPUTATIONAL". "Packed-decimal", which can be COMP-3/COMPUTATIONAL-3/PACKED-DECIMAL, is an "internal" format for a decimal number. It is not about "compacting" or saving space in itself (although that is one way it is used).

Comment: Where is your data coming from (compiler/Operating System) and where are you running it? One-long-line means the data you are looking at has no "record separator". Perhaps the COBOL program didn't write separators, perhaps they were deliberately (by accident) dropped in a transfer process to where you see them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest having a look at the [Last Cobol Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17448008/convert-mainframe-binary-to-ascii-using-any-open-source-code-or-tool)

But the [RecordEditor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/record-editor/?source=recommended) will let you view / edit Cobol Files using a Cobol Copybook. In the RecordEditor you can export the file as Csv, Xml if you want.

As mentioned in the [Last Cobol Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17448008/convert-mainframe-binary-to-ascii-using-any-open-source-code-or-tool) there are several solution for Reading Cobol files in Java and probably some in other languages.

---

To import the Cobol Copybook into the RecordEditor,
 Select:     **Record Layout** >>> **Import Cobol Copybook**

[image: Import_Cobol_Copybook]

The File-Structure controls how the file is read. Use a *File-Structure* of **Fixed length Binary** if all the records are of the same length (no carraige return).

Other Structures supported include

- Standard Text files  *File Structures*: ** ..Text.. **
- Cobol Variable Record Length Files. These Typically have a Record-Length followed by the Data. There are versions for Mainframes, Open-Cobol, Fujitsu.
- The **Default** File structure will choose the most likely **File-Structure** based on the **Record-Definition**. In your case it should choose **Fixed length Binary** because there is a binary Field in the Definition.

**Note:** From Record Editor 0.94.4, with a *File-Structure* of **Fixed Length Binary** you can edit Fixed Length Text files in a basic Text Editor if you want.

**Note:** I am the author of RecordEditor

### Answer Updates 2017/08/09

#### Conversion Utilities

For simple Cobol files these conversion utilities (based on JRecord) could be used:

- [CobolToCsv][5]
- [CobolToXml][6]
- [Cobol To Json][7]

#### RecordEditor

The [RecordEditor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8gvf.png) has a Generate option for generating Java / JRecord code.
See [RecordEditor Code Generation notes][8]

[image]

Comment: Really thanks for the answer. Now imagine that the sequential file is all in one line, there is any option in your program to put a line break by the record lenght?

Comment: Yes, there is Field File-Structure which controls how the file is Read. Set the File-Structure to Fixed-Length-Binary. You could also get away with Default because it switch's to Fixed-Length binary when there are binary fields