# How to unpack COMP digits using Java?

Tags: ascii, mainframe, ebcdic, packed-decimal

I had found this useful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20342804/how-to-unpack-comp-3-digits-using-java) for unpacked COMP-3 digit, but i need to unpack COMP digit this time, is anyone know how to unpack it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most Cobol compilers Comp is a big endian binary integer. For the mainframe only 2/4/8 bytes are supported. So For signed values

```
  03  Signed-Num     pic s9(4) comp.
```

if you have the value in an array of bytes you can do

```
BigInteger value = new BigInteger(byteArray);
```

Alternatively you could use the *readShort()*, *readInt()* and *readLong()* methods of [DataInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html)

Finally [JRecord](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jrecord/) will let you read Cobol files with a Cobol copybook

Answer (score 1):

IBM Provides a library of Java methods to simplify interactions with z/OS services and data formats.  An overview can be found here [jZOS Toolkit](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_8.0.0/com.ibm.java.zsecurity.api.80.doc/com.ibm.jzos/overview-summary.html)

Here is a link to [PackedDecimal Operations](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_8.0.0/com.ibm.java.api.80.doc/com.ibm.dataaccess/com/ibm/dataaccess/PackedDecimal.html)

Here are others for managing binary data [ByteArrayUnmarshaller](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_8.0.0/com.ibm.java.api.80.doc/com.ibm.dataaccess/com/ibm/dataaccess/PackedDecimal.html)