# Converting EBCDIC to ASCII in java

Tags: java, ascii, inputstream, cobol, ebcdic

I am supposed to convert an EBCDIC file to ASCII by using Java. So far I have this code:

```
public class Migration {
    InputStreamReader reader;
    StringBuilder builder;

    public Migration(){
        try {
            reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("C:\\TI3\\Legacy Systemen\\Week 3\\Oefening 3\\inputfile.dat"),
                   java.nio.charset.Charset.forName("ibm500") );
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        builder = new StringBuilder();
    }

    public void read() throws IOException {
        int theInt;
        while((theInt = reader.read()) != -1){
            char theChar = (char) theInt;
            builder.append(theChar);

        }

        reader.close();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

The file description is the following:

```
 02 KDGEX.
      05 B1-LENGTH PIC S9(04) USAGE IS COMP.
      05 B1-CODE PIC S9(04) USAGE IS COMP.
      05 B1-NUMBER PIC X(08).
      05 B1-PPR-NAME PIC X(06).
      05 B1-PPR-FED PIC 9(03).
      05 B1-PPR-RNR PIC S9(08) USAGE IS COMP.
      05 B1-DATA.
        10 B1-VBOND PIC 9(02).
        10 B1-KONST.
          20 B1-AFDEL PIC 9(03).
          20 B1-KASSIER PIC 9(03).
          20 B1-DATZIT-DM PIC 9(04).
        10 B1-BETWYZ PIC X(01).
        10 B1-RNR PIC X(13).
        10 B1-BETKOD PIC 9(02).
        10 B1-VOLGNR-INF PIC 9(02).
        10 B1-QUAL-PREST PIC 9(03).
        10 B1-REKNUM PIC 9(12).
        10 B1-REKNR REDEFINES B1-REKNUM.
          20 B1-REKNR-PART1 PIC 9(03).
          20 B1-REKNR-PART2 PIC 9(07).
          20 B1-REKNR-PART3 PIC 9(02).
        10 B1-VOLGNR-M30 PIC 9(03).
        10 B1-OMSCHR.
          15 B1-OMSCHR1 PIC X(14).
          15 B1-OMSCHR2 PIC X(14).
        10 B1-OMSCHR-INF REDEFINES B1-OMSCHR.
          15 B1-AANT-PREST PIC 9(02).
          15 B1-VERSTR PIC 9(01).
          15 B1-LASTDATE PIC 9(06).
          15 B1-HONOR PIC 9(06).
          15 B1-RIJKN PIC X(13).
        10 FILLER--1 PIC 9(02).
        10 B1-INFOREK PIC 9(01).
        10 B1-BEDRAG-EUR PIC 9(08).
        10 B1-BEDRAG-DV PIC X(01).
        10 B1-BEDRAG-RMG-DV REDEFINES B1-BEDRAG-DV PIC X(01).
      05 FILLER PIC X(5).
```

We can ignore the first 2 bytes on every line. The problem is the bytes where there's a USAGE IS COMP since the reader is not converting them properly, I think I am supposed to read these as bytes or something, though I have no idea how.

Comment: COMP with 1-4 digits is a two-byte binary. COMP with 5-9 digits is a four-byte binary. It's coming from an IBM Mainframe (most likely) so it will be Big Endian, if that matters. X'0010' will be a value of 16, as will X'00000010'. All the other data is plain unsigned character data, so could be treated as big chunks of characters if more convenient. It *may* be that the first four bytes are not required. A variable-length record is preceded by two two-byte binary fields, containing length and zero. This may be a coincidence here.

Comment: Just to add, that whoever gives you that file is making it more difficult for you. If *all* the fields that you need were plain character fields, the EBCDIC to ASCII conversion can just be done by whatever utility is giving you the file - you'd have no program to write, no wheel to re-invent.

Comment: If you can't get the change at the other end, here's an existing wheel http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17448008/convert-mainframe-binary-to-ascii-using-any-open-source-code-or-tool

Comment: Thankyou for all the replies, I will take a look at it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I am interpreting this format correctly you have a binary file format with fixed-length records. Some of these records are not character data (COBOL computational fields?)

So, you will have to read the records using a more low-level approach processing individual fields of each record:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Record {
  private byte[] kdgex = new byte[2]; // COMP
  private byte[] b1code = new byte[2]; // COMP
  private byte[] b1number = new byte[8]; // DISPLAY
  // other fields

  public void read(DataInput data) throws IOException {
    data.readFully(kdgex);
    data.readFully(b1code);
    data.readFully(b1number);
    // other fields
  }

  public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
    out.write(kdgex);
    out.write(b1code);
    out.write(b1number);
    // other fields
  }
}
```

Here I've used byte arrays for the first three fields of the record but you could use other more suitable types where appropriate (like a `short` for the first field with [readShort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readShort%28%29).) *Note: my interpretation of the field widths is likely wrong; it is just an example.*

The [DataInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) is generally used as a [DataInput](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html) implementation.

Since all characters in the source and target encodings use a one-octet-per code point you should be able to transcode the character data fields using a method like this:

```
public static byte[] transcodeField(byte[] source, Charset from, Charset to) {
  byte[] result = new String(source, from).getBytes(to);
  if (result.length != source.length) {
    throw new AssertionError(result.length + "!=" + source.length);
  }
  return result;
}
```

*I suggest tagging your question with COBOL (assuming that is the source of this format) so that someone else can speak with more authority on the format of the data source.*

Comment: As Bill Woodger pointed out in his comments... An IBM COBOL S9(04) COMP field is a two byte 2's complement big-endian binary number with the sign in the leftmost bit. An S9(08) COMP is similar but occupies 4 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

I also faced same issue like converting EBCDIC to ASCII string.
Please find the code below to convert a single EBCDIC to ASCII string.

```
public class EbcdicConverter
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
        throws Exception
    {
        String ebcdicString =<your EBCDIC string>;
        // convert String into InputStream
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(ebcdicString.getBytes());
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        int line;
         while((line = is.read()) != -1) {
             baos.write((char)line);
         }
         String str = baos.toString("Cp500");
         System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: How would that deal with the non-character fields in the question? If you don't have non-character data, just do it in the file transfer, don't write convoluted code for it.