# java program to convert EBCDIC to ASCII

Tags: java, ascii, ebcdic

I wrote a simple java program to convert EBCDIC to ASCII. It's not working correctly. Here is what I did

```
Step 1: Convert ASCII file to EBCDIC using the following command :

 dd if=sampleInput.txt of=ebcdic.txt conv=ebcdic

 sampleInput.txt has following line :

input 12 12
```

Step 1: generated ebcdic.txt

Now, wrote following java program to convert ebcdic to ascii

```
public class CoboDataFilelReaderTest {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

     int line;
     InputStreamReader rdr = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("/Users/rr/Documents/workspace/EBCDIC_TO_ASCII/ebcdic.txt"), java.nio.charset.Charset.forName("ibm500"));
        while((line = rdr.read()) != -1) {
            System.out.println(line);
    }
    }
 }
```

It gave me wrong output, the output looks something like this :

```
115
97
109
112
108
101
32
49
50
32
49
50
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20349491/converting-ebcdic-to-ascii-in-java

Comment: It look like you are opening the FileInputStream on your users directory "Users/rr/". Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Try IBM-1047 as charset.

Comment: Lan - yes, since the file is located at "/Users/rr/Documents/workspace/EBCDIC_TO_ASCII/ebcdic.txt", i am just pointing it there

Comment: Hannes : IBM-1047 didn't change anything either:(

Comment: Your output can be translated to `sample 12 12`, are you sure the content of ebcdic.txt is correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By calling `rdr.read()` you read one byte. If you want to read one character of text instead of it's numeric representation, you could cast it to a character like this:

```
int numericChar;
InputStreamReader rdr = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("/Users/rr/Documents/workspace/EBCDIC_TO_ASCII/ebcdic.txt"), java.nio.charset.Charset.forName("ibm500"));
while((numericChar = rdr.read()) != -1) {
        System.out.println((char) numericChar);
}
```

If you'd write each `numericChar` to a file as one byte, the both files would look the same. But you are writing to the console and not to a file so it represents the content as numbers instead of interpreting them as character.

---

If you want to output the content line by line you could do it like this:

```
int numericChar;
InputStreamReader rdr = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("/Users/rr/Documents/workspace/EBCDIC_TO_ASCII/ebcdic.txt"), java.nio.charset.Charset.forName("ibm500"));
while((numericChar = rdr.read()) != -1) {
    System.out.print((char) numericChar);
}
```

This will not start a new line after each character.

The difference between `System.out.println()` and `System.out.print()` is that `println` will start a new line after printing the value by appending the newline character `\n`.

Comment: It worked, thanks. But it printed single character in 1 line like s \n a \n m\n p\n\nl\ne\n1\n2\n1\n2...How do I print it line by line as in input?

Comment: You are welcom :D If you like the answer please don't forget to click the accept button :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast `line` (which is a terrible name for an `int` representing a single character) to `char`, like this.

```
System.out.println((char) line);
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. But it printed single character in 1 line like s \n a \n m\n p\n\nl\ne\n1\n2\n1\n2...How do I print it line by line as in input?

Comment: @user2942227 Do you understand what `println` does?