# How to convert ebcdic format to ASCII using Scala?

Tags: scala, ascii, ebcdic

How do I convert **EBCDIC** format to **ASCII** using **Scala programming**?

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically are you stuck on?

Comment: i can convert EBCDIC format to ASCII in Unix by this 'dd if=input_file of=output_file conv=ascii' but i want do same conversion in scala.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of

```
import java.nio.file._

val ebcdicBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/whereEver/myEbcdicFile"))
val asciiBytes = new String(ebcdicBytes, "Cp1047").getBytes("ASCII")
```

might work.

Comment: i can convert EBCDIC format to ASCII in Unix by this 'dd if=input_file of=output_file conv=ascii' but i want do same conversion in scala.

Comment: Ok. The above code converts ebcdic to ascii using Scala (at least it should: I didn't bother testing it on any ebcdic-encoded files). Does it answer your question? If not: is anything unclear? I mean, it's like 2 lines, everything is built-in already...

Comment: Good. It looks like you should have enough material for an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) by now. It would be nice if you could somehow provide an example of the file for which the problem occurs.

Comment: i need to do same as this in scala https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20349491/converting-ebcdic-to-ascii-in-java